# How to handle V-show dynamically

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuejs3

I am trying to build an Ecommerce shopping website. I import data from JSON file and by using v-for loop I am able to print data. There is one section in each order that is **Show Order Details** option, after clicking it one more section called **order details** will show. I used v-show tag to open the details section. But when I am clicking one show order details option in every three orders show details part is opening, it's not taking the ID properly in v-show. I tried with v-bind, but that doesn't work. Please help me.

**MyOrders.vue**

```html
<template>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-3">
        <h1 class="">MyOrders</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="form-class">
        <div class="col-md-12" v-for="item in MyOrders"
             :key="item.id">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-6">
              {{ item.order_quantity }}
            </div>
            <div class="col-6">
              <button v-bind:key="item.id" @click="active = !active">Show Order Details</button>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-6">
              <span class="text-dark">{{ item.order_number }}</span>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-6">
              <span class="text-dark">{{ item.order_tracking_id }}</span>
            </div>
          </div>
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-6">Order details
                <span class="text-dark" v-show="active">{{ item.order_details }}</span>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
import {myOrders} from "./MyOrders";
export default {
  name: "Myorders",
  data() {
    return {
      Myorders: myOrders,
      active: false,
    }
  },
  mounted(){
  },
  methods: {}
}
</script>
<style>
</style>
```

**MyOrder.js**

```js
export const myOrders= [
    {
        "id": 1,
        "order_number": "11",
        "order_quantity": "10",
        "order_tracking_id": "1009",
        "order_details": "The order will ship to London",
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "order_number": "17",
        "order_quantity": "9",
        "order_tracking_id": "1055",
        "order_details": "The order will ship to Australia",
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "order_number": "15",
        "order_quantity": "13",
        "order_tracking_id": "1087",
        "order_details": "The order will ship to France",
    }
]
```

Comment: active state is used to control the visibility of the order details for all orders. This means that when you toggle the visibility of the order details for one order, it will also toggle the visibility for all the other orders.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `item.id` instead of boolean to toggle details :

```js
const app = Vue.createApp({
  data() {
    return {
      myOrders: [{"id": 1, "order_number": "11", "order_quantity": "10",   "order_tracking_id": "1009", "order_details": "The order will ship to London",}, {"id": 2, "order_number": "17", "order_quantity": "9","order_tracking_id": "1055",       "order_details": "The order will ship to Australia",}, {"id": 3, "order_number": "15", "order_quantity": "13", "order_tracking_id": "1087", "order_details": "The order will ship to France",}],
      active: null,
    }
  },
  methods: {
    toggleDetails(id) {
      this.active = id === this.active ? null : id
    }
  }
})
app.mount('#demo')
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3/dist/vue.global.prod.js"></script>
  <div id="demo">
    <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-3">
        <h1 class="">MyOrders</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="form-class">
        <div class="col-md-12" v-for="item in myOrders" :key="item.id">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-6">
              {{ item.order_quantity }}
            </div>
            <div class="col-6">
              <button v-bind:key="item.id" @click="toggleDetails(item.id)">Show Order Details</button>
            </div>
          </div>
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-6">Order details
                <span class="text-dark" v-show="active === item.id">{{ item.order_details }}</span>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```